# GCP code editor python debugger does not show its output

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Testing the GCP code editor I noticed that the python debugging console does not show its own output. Eg for `1+1` it should show `2`. I know from my vscode that sometimes the output is shown in another console/terminal. Any suggestions on how to get the input within the debugging console?

The debugging console in GCP:
[image: gcp debugger example]

My debugging console on my local machine as reference:
[image: local vsc debugger example]

Comment: You are trying to enter `1+1` is the shell. That won't work. Start Python first.

Comment: @John I added a reference to show what kind of behavior I am expecting from the debug console. From my understanding starting python in your python debug console should not be necessary(?)

Comment: It is necessary if you are entering Python at a command prompt. Notice the error `bash: 1+1: command not found`.

Comment: No matter what I type into this console I cannot find the output. Also `bash: 1+1: command not found` is nowhere to be seen. Any ideas where I could find the output or make it visible?

Comment: That output `bash: 1+1: command not found` is in your first screenshot.

Comment: `bash: 1+1: command not found` took place before the debugger was started. I did that to see if I was still in the bash shell.